# Move CollectionView content above keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to move CollectionView Cells above the keyboard when keyboard its appear. I just got keyboard size then i changed UIEdgeInsets the bottom of Collection view but nothing happens

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(collectionV)
    collectionV.dataSource = self
    collectionV.delegate = self
    collectionV.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionV.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 45, right: 0)
    collectionV.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionV.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

@objc func handleKeyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    print("will show?")

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        let animationDuration: TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

        ContainerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -keyboardSize.height
        collectionV.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height+8, right: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }
    }
}

@objc func handleKeyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {

    print("will hide?")
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let animationDuration: TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

    ContainerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = 0
    self.collectionV.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 45, right: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

On Simulator when i press (⌘k) its working(the Cells move above), but when i click on TextField to show keyboard isn't working (Cells not moving) and i still get (print("will show")), Also on real device not working.

That makes me confusing, Any help to figure out what's wrong here?

**Edit Fix:** `let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue`

Thanks to @MichaelVorontsov

Comment: Value  at `notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]` is actually represents frame of keyboard before notification was sent. In iOS11 it has 0 height.  Try `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov oh, Thank you so much i really appreciated that, Worked!

Comment: =============

Comment: what is ContainerViewBottomAnchor here?

Comment: @GoribDeveloper Its Constraints to move the view And my problem just solved.

Comment: can you please provide the code for the ContainerViewBottomAnchor please